# ros.properties is missing

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Mmmh, I become crazy ! I followed the wiki of rosjava but when I do rosmake I get the message

```
/home/.../my_demo/build.xml:21: ros.properties is missing.  Please type 'rosmake' first
```

What I have to do?

Poseidonius

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12220/ros.properties-is-missing/) by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 427 on 2011-12-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-12-05**:
Have you rosmaked rosjava (separately)? I think there needs to be some bootstrapping first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROSJava generates the file ros.properties. To generate it is necessary to execute the command rosmake but in the case of rosjava, it is necessary to udpate the file makefile with the following line:

```
include $(shell rospack find rosjava_bootstrap)/rosjava.mk
```

Cheers

Juan Antonio

---

Originally posted by [Juan Antonio Breña Moral](https://answers.ros.org/users/464/juan-antonio-bre%C3%B1a-moral/) with karma: 274 on 2012-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [morrowsend](https://answers.ros.org/users/1084/morrowsend/) on 2012-01-22**:
I've done this, and followed the webpage instructions exactly (started over multiple times as well). ros.properties is there, yet I still get this error.